# What are these time units smaller than seconds: 1/60ths of a second

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, units

I am using Blender to edit videos. I see strip time units listed with three colon separators, like: **HH:MM:SS:??**. So, what are those smallest units? 1/60 of a second? 1/100th of a second. Or should the third colon actually be a period to indicate a decimal point? I have this time: **02:18:46:29**. Is that for 46 and *29/60ths* seconds or 46 and *29/100ths* of a second - *46.29*? I could find no documentation on this or any way to control time representation in preferences. I've never see a time unit like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Frames or Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds (depending on your settings);

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks. So, I was looking at the strip properties to the right of the sequence display with its timeline. So the preference you identified controls the timeline display, horizontally with the clips. By changing it to the different possibilities, I determined in that display of the clip timing, it is HH:MM:SS:FF, that is the last number is the frame number. That is still interesting to me, given that frames don't need to start on an even number of seconds, but anyway. Thanks.